# Lennard-Jones potential, distance $r$ for minimum energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, differentiation, calculus

I'm sorry if the question seems stupid. I found (wikipedia) that the [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) has it's minimum at a distance of
$$r = 2^{\frac{1}{6}}\sigma.$$

If $U(r)_{min} = -\epsilon$

$$U(r) = 4\epsilon\left[ \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{6} \right].$$

$$-\frac{1}{4} =  (\frac{\sigma}{r})^{12} - (\frac{\sigma}{r})^{6}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minima is found by differentiating and setting the derivative to zero.

$$
\frac{dU}{dr}= -4\epsilon \left[12 \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12}\frac{1}{r}- 6 \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{6}\frac{1}{r}\right]
$$

Setting the term in the square bracket to zero yields the correct expression for the position of the minima:

$$
\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{6}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

or,
$$
r=2^{\frac{1}{6}}\sigma.
$$

It is possible that you didn't do the derivative correctly.

Comment: I didn't do the derivative at all. I didn't know I had to do it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima Maybe brushing on some calculus will help.

Comment: @proxima If you know that $U=-\epsilon$ at the minimum, you don’t have to differentiate.

Comment: @G.Smith you are probably right, but I don't see how.

Comment: @proxima Solve $U(r_\text{min})=-\epsilon$ for $r_\text{min}$.

Comment: @G.Smith Yeah, that's what I did. I'll edit my post. I can't get the answer.

Comment: @proxima At $r=\sigma$ the right side of your new equation is 0 and the left side is -1/4. Clearly that value of $r$ does *not* solve the equation.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake. However, even there I can't get the right answer.

Comment: You can turn it into a quadratic equation with a simple change of variables. Do you know how to solve a quadratic?

Comment: $$x =  - \frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

However, I don't see the simple change of variables.

Comment: @proxima What happens if you define $x=\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^6$ and write the equation in terms of $x$ instead of $r$?

Comment: Oh... I see. Thanks for your patience. Sorry I didn't see that earlier.

Comment: @proxima Note: The calculus method in this answer is more powerful, because it does not require knowing the minimum value of $U$ in advance.