# How to determine the spring constant in a Lennard-Jones potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I found the values of $u_1,u_2$ for 2 differents posistions ($r_1,r_2$) and I now have to determine the spring constant (k).

I'm thinking about using $$F= -kx$$ with $F = -\frac{du}{dr}$ then

$$U = \int -kr \cdot dr =-k\frac{r^2}{2}$$

I'm wondering if I can use $r = r_2$ and $U= U_2$ or I'm completely wrong by using $F = -kx$

Comment: Here is what I suggest you should do: (1) Plot the potential, (2) Ask yourself in which region the potential looks similar to the potential of an harmonic oscillator, (3) Approximate the potential in this region. By using these steps I hope you understand what it going on and why it makes sense to describe the LJ potential using a spring constant $k$.

Comment: You probably find an answer in this math stackexchange post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063866/restoring-force-of-a-lennard-jones-potential

Answer (score 0):

In the $n$-exp notation we write for the Lennard-Jones potential:

$$U_{LJ}(r)=\varepsilon\Big[\Big(\frac{r_0}{r}\Big)^{2n}-2\Big(\frac{r_0}{r}\Big)^n\Big]$$

where $n=6$ and $\varepsilon$ is the bonding energy. Applying an harmonic approximation at the potential minimum (at ${\displaystyle U(r_{m})=-\varepsilon }{\displaystyle U(r_{m})=-\varepsilon }$), the exponent ${\displaystyle n}$ and the energy parameter ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$  can be related to the spring constant:

$$k=2\varepsilon\Big(\frac{n}{r_0}\Big)^2$$

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential#Application_of_the_Lennard-Jones_potential_in_molecular_modeling).

Comment: I saw that, but I'm not sure to fully understand how from your first equation you get $k = 2\epsilon(\frac{n}{r_0})^2$

Comment: Yes, there's no derivation given for that leap and I don't really know how to do it either. Maybe  another member?

Comment: The wiki text stated exactly what you have to do: "Applying an harmonic approximation at the potential minimum the exponent $n$
 and the energy parameter 
$\epsilon$  can be related to the spring constant."

Comment: Isn't the spring constant in the harmonic approximation defined to $k \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 U(r)}{\mathrm{d}r^2} (r_0)$?

Comment: @Jakob   $k \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 U(r)}{\mathrm{d}r^2} (r_0)$?

Comment: @Gert : See also the comment on OP's post, where I linked a math stackexchange question. Edit: The answer, fortunately, coincides with $k$ given in Wikipedia for $n=6$.

Comment: @Gert Check out my answer and the link inside it, I've described how to arrive at the formula :)

Comment: @Jakob I already have, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've described the method to calculate the frequency of oscillations for arbitrary potentials in my answer to this question: [Calculating Frequency of Oscillations About a Stable Equilibrium Point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/574627/157014). I've adapted my answer here from the one there.

The basic idea is this:

1. First, find the (local) minimum of the potential you are interested in, using the standard methods. In your case, it should be easy to show that the minimum occurs at $$r=r_0.$$
2. Next, perform a [Taylor Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) about this equilibrium point up to the second order. The expansion about a point $r_0$ is thus:

$$U(r) = U(r_0) + U'(r_0) (r - r_0) + \frac{U''(r_0)}{2!} (r-r_0)^2 + \text{ higher powers of } (r-r_0)\,\,...$$

3. Since $U(r)$ is a minimum at $r_0$, $U'(r_0)$ is zero, and $U''(r_0)>0$. Thus, very close to $r_0$ the function $U(r)$ behaves as a constant plus a positive quadratic term. In other words, close to the minimum it looks like the potential energy of a harmonic oscillator! (Of course, this is only true for very small oscillations, i.e. when $r-r_0$ is very small.)
4. The last step is to realise that since you have approximated your function about $r_0$ as $$U(r) = U(r_0) + \frac{1}{2}U''(r_0) (r-r_0)^2,$$

you can compare it to an ideal harmonic oscillator and easily see that the "spring constant" is given by $$k = U''(r_0)!$$

This means that very close to the point $r_0$, this system behaves very much like a harmonic oscillator with this spring constant. Plugging in the values, you should see (as mentioned in the other answers) that $$k = 2 \epsilon \left(\frac{n}{r_0}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the previous answers, you take a harmonic oscillator potential energy and differentiate it twice, and you get the spring constant. So it only makes sense to take  the second-order term of the Taylor expansion of the Lennard Jones potential evaluated around the potential minimum.

Here's a post that shows how to arrive at the minimum of the Lennard-Jones potential for n=6:

[Lennard-Jones potential, distance $r$ for minimum energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609558/lennard-jones-potential-distance-r-for-minimum-energy)